# HTML Lang ISO Code

Tags: seo, search-results, language

I have a multi-language site for English and Chinese (Hong Kong). My previous setting for  Chinese Hong Kong (zh-hk) had:
`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="zh-hk" xml:lang="zh-hk">`

Shortly, I began to notice browser with other Chinese language sub-codes like zh-tw and zh-cn were seeing my English site in search engines instead of Chinese Hong Kong (zh-hk), which makes sense.

I want to change my html lang to:
`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="zh" xml:lang="zh">`

Would this cover all Chinese language settings? Also, would Google prefer to show pages that match language subcodes of the browser/country (zh-hk for Hong Kong, zh-cn for Taiwan) than a general language code (zh)?

Comment: I like to mention that the search terms are in English (e.g. hp officejet). People with zh-hk are served with my Chinese site, and the rest are served with the English version.

Answer (score 1):

> ...would Google prefer to show pages that match language subcodes

From: [Google Webmaster Central - Working with multilingual websites](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html)

> Keep in mind that Google ignores all code-level language information,
>   from “lang” attributes to Document Type Definitions (DTD). Some web
>   editing programs create these attributes automatically, and therefore
>   they aren’t very reliable when trying to determine the language of a
>   webpage.

Comment: I read this page as well, but I think it plays a role in search engine. It doesn't make sense that it loads the English part of my site to users who do not have zh-hk settings.

Comment: I would have thought that your English site would only be returned in Google SERPs if the user searched for an English phrase (irrespective of what language the browser is set as)? Or is this not the case? If I search for a Chinese Hong Kong phrase then it would be reasonable to expect pages returned in the SERPs that are in that language (since that is where the phrase would most likely be found), despite my browser being set to "en-GB". By default Google searches for pages in "Any Language", but this can be set in Advanced Search to a specific language if required. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: That would make sense. When you search in google.com.hk, you would be automatically switched to Chinese HK. Google would show more of Chinese websites than English. My product has mix of English and Chinese characters (e.g. HP Officejet [chinese characters]). For some reason, people with Zh-tw and Zh-cn are seeing the English part when they search for HP Officejet.

Comment: **Correction**
For some reason, people with Zh-tw and Zh-cn are seeing the English _version_ when they search for HP Officejet.

Comment: If I search on google.com.hk then the language defaults to "Any Language" (I'm not logged in to Google), however the _location_ is set to "Pages from Hong Kong". Pages returned in the SERPs are certainly biased towards this geographic region, however, the language of these results is certainly dependent on the language of my search phrase. I'm not sure what is happening with "HP Officejet", but maybe this has something to do with Google's translation? eg. If I translate "HP Officejet" (English) it is returned as "惠普Officejet" (Chinese Simplified) - a marked similarity with the English.

Comment: I guess Google HK is setup to geotarget the language base on the IP. It loads the Chinese version for me when I clear my cache and cookies, even though my laptop was bought back home in Canada. The data in GA show they are searching for "HP Officejet" rather than the translation. What I mean previously is my Chinese version has 'HP Officejet 代用墨盒' and the English version has HP Officejet Compatible Ink Cartridge. Someone in China with zh-cn setting would see the English version instead when they search for HP Officejet. Thanks for looking into it w3d